# JavaScript moving slightly down a Message (div)?

Tags: css, javascript

Is there a way to move down by some pixel a div with a text inside? (Maybe using jQuery or w/e)

The effect I would get is like when stackoverflow shows at top the yellow message (for a badge) But I need it inside a page, without moving down all the rest of the page

EXAMPLE:

http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/7324/senzatitolo2mb.jpg

(I would add a fade effect too while the message is moving down)

Ps. Please consider the message can be more than 1 (just like stackoverflow at top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with jQuery this would be done like:

```
<div id="message">Some message</div>
$("#message").slideDown(500); //where 500 is the time effect in miliseconds..
```

**Online demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/NzPfM/

Se more about jQuery effects here: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

If you want to slide it down and fade it in at the same time, then you should use .animate() instead, something like:

```
$("#message").animate({height:"30px", opacity:1 },500);
```

**Online demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/NzPfM/1/

UPDATE: If you want to avoid moving other content while animating you can use `position:absolute` in css see demo below:

**Demo avoiding push down:** http://jsfiddle.net/NzPfM/2/

Comment: problem with this solution is that it pushes down content below, which the demo doesn't show because there is no content. And this is specifically what the OP asked not to happen

Comment: if you notice the stackoverflow message does push the page, but if you want to avoid that, add position:absolute to the element in css

Comment: see it working with position:absolute here: http://jsfiddle.net/NzPfM/2/ note that i push the content with margin otherwise the message would overlap

Comment: @martin: can't I set a container with fixed height to "cointain" the exspansion to make the rest of the page moving down?

Comment: @amosrivera: i don't think i can use position:absolute becase the message should appear in the middle of a text too

Comment: @amos: OK thanks to your help i am using ur second solution: see it http://jsfiddle.net/ySg7p/

Comment: @amo: last quick question? Do i need to put the code in the $.onload or i can safely put just above the div ?

Comment: it is recommended placing the code within the document.ready wrapper like `$(function(){ /* code here */ });`, you can put the `<script>` tag basically anywhere but it is better to put it in the head that way you know where to find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the div to `position:absolute` and then animate it down using `jQuery.animate` to change the `top` style.

read about jQuery.animate here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

You can see a simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/NsxTa/

Note: This method as opposed to using the `slideDown` will actually slide the entire div down from it's hiding place, where as `slideDown` will just reveal statically positioned content, which imo looks really awefull

Comment: thanks for the example! but i don't want the message going over the text at bottom

Comment: In that case you either need to leave room for the sliding div, or you need to let it push the text down, you can't have both

Comment: i can leave the room for the sliding that's not a problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your page is not laying inside some container with position-absolute, 
adding a container element as fist child of the body will push down render all the rest of the page.
(container - any HTML tag that contains HTML. usually DIV).

This is an example using pure javascript:

http://jsfiddle.net/osher/ByngB/

connect the "add" to your messaging event, or render the  on the server
connect the "remove" to the close button of the message bar
and that will be all :)

```
function $e(s){ return document.getElementById(s) }

function add(){
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.innerHTML = "your message: " + $e("txt").value;
    document.body.insertBefore(d, document.body.firstChild);
}

function remove(){
    // assuming that your page content is wrapped in a div with ID="content"
    if (document.body.firstChild.id == "content") return;

    document.body.removeChild( document.body.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle example with a little more power.
Have fun :)